# debug two applications output logs in one console vscode

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, launch

I have many java microservices applications running on `visual-studio-code` successfully.
When I start debug each one outputs its own internal console.
Is there any way to join console log outputs ammong many applications on workspace?

my launch.json

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "compounds": [
        {
            "name": "graphql_server_client",
            "configurations": ["graphql-server","graphql-client"],  // how output logs in the same internalConsole debug
        }
    ],
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "java",
            "name": "graphql-server",
            "console": "internalConsole", // how output logs in the same internalConsole debug
            "request": "launch",
            "envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/local.env",
            "mainClass": "example.graphqlserver.Application",
            "projectName": "graphql-server"
        },
        {
            "type": "java",
            "name": "graphql-client",
            "console": "internalConsole", // how output logs in the same internalConsole debug
            "envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/local.env",
            "request": "launch",
            "mainClass": "example.graphqlclient.Application",
            "projectName": "graphql-client"
        }
    ]
}
```

Currently I'm working arroung write logs in the same file to see all logs together. is there any way to do this on debug console visual-studio ?

Answer (score 1):

Add `compounds` in launch.json:

```
"compounds":[
    {
        "name":"server/client",
        "configuration":["graphql-server","graphql-client",]
    }
]
```

Choose `server/client` in the debug selection lists then start debugging.

Detailed information please refer to [Compound Launc Configurations](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/debugging#_compound-launch-configurations).

Comment: This way i can start all microservice together but I have still choose all ouput console on debug list. is there any to get all output together in one selection debug. Currently I'm working arround wtiting alll microservice logs into a single file.

Comment: @DilermandoLima. I thought you want [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SAftZ.gif), which creates two java debug process but show the result in one of them. So you only want to create one java debug process?

Comment: I think I was not so clearly on my post. I refreshed it about wrint logs console in the same place

Comment: @DilermandoLima. It's more kind of VSCode questions but not specific java extension. You may ask in [github/vscode](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues) for more help.